# SSL_CTX_set_verify() callback and current depth

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm writing my own callback function in C for [`SSL_CTX_set_verify()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html) to perform additional certificate checks (when the `preverify_ok` parameter is `1`). However, I want to perform the checks *only* for the leaf certificate (depth = 0).

There is the function [`X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/X509_STORE_CTX_get_error.html) that gets the depth of the error; but I want the current depth even when there is no error so I can perform my additional checks only when depth=0.  (Note that the function `SSL_CTX_get_verify_depth()` returns the depth *limit* and *not* the current depth.)

Is there any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spite of the name, *during the verify process* `error_depth` is indeed the current certificate being checked. See the `while` loop in `internal_verify` in `crypto/x509/x509_vfy.c`. If either the callback or any builtin check -- here signature or expired, in other places in `X509_verify_cert` revocation, policy, etc. -- decides a cert is bad, verify logic returns with `error_depth` left at the cert that caused verify to return, and a subsequent call from 'above' finds that value which identifies the 'error' cert.