# SSL_CTX_set_verify() callback and depth of root CA

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm writing my own callback function in C for `SSL_CTX_set_verify()` to perform additional certificate checks (when the `preverify_ok` parameter is 1). However, I want to perform the checks only for the root CA certificate.

Within the callback, the function `X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth()` [gets the current depth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33248873/99089) where a depth of 0 is the leaf certificate. But how can I find out what the depth of the root CA certificate is? I.e. the depth of the *first* time my callback is called so I can compare it against the current depth.

Yes, there is the `SSL_CTX_get_verify_depth()` function, but that returns the depth *limit* (if any), so that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the root CA, the current cert and issuer cert in the Store Context will be same. So, a check like below in your code should do the trick:

```
if(X509_STORE_CTX_get0_current_issuer(ctx) == X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx))
{
  //Do the special root certificate related checks.
}
```

Comment: While this is true in most cases it does not need to be. The trust anchor does not need to be a self-signed CA as in most cases, but it is enough to be any CA which is in the trust store.